# Include html file in page without applying original pages CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, include

firstly I am new here, so forgive me if this questions seems poorly written.

Is there any way to include a separate html file without applying the referenced CSS/JS of the original?

For instance, I have a file "index.php" with several references to external style sheets.

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
```

I then include another file navbar.html with its own external style sheet reference.

```
<link href="navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

However, the CSS and JS of the original file always seem to apply to the included file, which unfortunately often leads to the included page being styled inappropriately.

Is there any way to include a page while applying only its desired CSS and JS?

Althou I find IFrames usefull, I am looking for a solution that does not use them, as they are not always browser compatible, and do not dynamically change shape. For instance if a navbar has a dropdown link it will not be shown because the iframe has a set size.

Comment: What you want is not clear. You want to include navbar.html in index.html. Ahead that is not clear of External Libraries.

Comment: Also if you can place your two files here than it would be easy to help you.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a way to include navbar.html, without applying the CSS and JS that is referenced in index.html, only the CSS referenced inside navbar.html

Comment: Ok but then you must have uncommon tags in navbar.html that of index.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, what does that mean?

Comment: Suppose you have class name ' navbar ' in navbar.html. So you must not have same class in your index.php, so there would be less chance of css overriding.

Comment: Ah I see. While I think this would work, for much of what I do this would take changing potentially hundreds of lines, as I typically use Bootstrap. Seems like the only answer though, so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do its not possible as per my knowledge.
Because when you include any file in html, in your case its navbar.html
When it render on browser ultimately it consider as single html file.
With all css / js applied to same html page.

So you can use different class names in your navbar.html and also in css.
So it will not affect to other index.html elements.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

the css can be covered,so you can use yours classname for the html style,so lang as you write the core css before yours css.

as well as the javascript, you can use the global variable to manage yours variable avoid global namespace pollution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. What do you mean by covering the CSS? I don't understand the 2'nd part at all

Comment: Answer must be when you are sure it will help the OP.